# Measuring time in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to measure the time of execution of a java class, when I used a script file with this and run "ruby file.rb" from the terminal works perfect always, and I always get values around 10 seconds:

```
ini = Time.now
`java file.class`
fin = Time.now
puts "#{fin-ini}"
```

but when I do the exactly same in a controller of a rails application always I get values like 5.626041666666666e-10

anyone knows what is happening

Answer (score 2):

> Most calculators and many computer programs present very large and
>   very small results in scientific notation. Because superscripted
>   exponents like 107 cannot always be conveniently displayed, the letter
>   E or e is often used to represent times ten raised to the power of
>   (which would be written as "x 10b") and is followed by the value of
>   the exponent.

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

There is a VERY small time between when `ini` is initialized and `fin` is and what you're seeing is the difference between the two.

All it really means is 5.626041666666666×10^(-10) or 0.0000000005626041666666666 seconds or milliseconds or whatever your unit of measure is.

If you're interested in rounding this, you can always do `#{(fin - ini).to_i}` which will convert it to an integer, 0.

Comment: So looks like when that part of the code in the controller is executed, ``java file.class`\` is returning almost immediately, without running the program. That is why the difference is infinitesimally small. Try adding some logging in the java program to ensure that the program is indeed called. 

The java program might not be accessible from the controller.

Comment: in fact in the java class I have something like this
      Thread.sleep(10000);
so... it will sleep 10 seconds aprox

Comment: Sorry guys, I realized that in the controller I have( '  )and don't ( ` ) so, it was just a simple string, not a excution from the console